# submiting form on document load

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form after the document is loaded. Why isn't this piece of code not working?

[EDIT]: The page is resubmitting to itself

[EDIT]: I am running on `Ubuntu 10.10 Firefox 3.6`

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="chat.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="displayname" id="displayname"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    promptusername();
});

function promptusername()
{
    $('#displayname').val(prompt("Enter your display name"));
    //if($('#displayname').val() != null){
        $('#myform').submit();
    //}
    //else{
        //promptusername();
    //}         
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the jquery in the page?

Comment: @Sarfraz yes, so the page is submitting it itself

Comment: Does work for me in FireFox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the fact the page can be redirected from `chat.php` and so it was !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try submitting the form without prompting for username

Comment: @experimentX above code is working in FF 3.6.14, chrome (latest) and not in IE8 as expected

Comment: i dont think so. It cant be related to OS. I tested on Ubuntu Its working.

Comment: i dont know, but this piece of junk doing nothing but just submitting itself again and again. But i think, it is working in jsfiddle.net. Any appreciation for testing.

Comment: and modify your answer a bit though i don't think i will accept. +1 is all i can do.

Comment: This is happening in IE 8 for me

Comment: happening for me on firefox also, i think i have to quit this whole idea